# nestjs is there a difference with or without async/await?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, nestjs

I was thinking there were no differences between:

```
@Post()
saveClient(@Param() params, @Body() createClientDto: ClientDto) {
   this.clientRepository.save(createClientDto);
  }
```

**and**

```
@Post()
  async saveClient(@Param() params, @Body() createClientDto: ClientDto) {
   await this.clientRepository.save(createClientDto);
  }
```

But without async/await the function returns void, and If an exception is occurred I get this:

*(node:62777) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection.
(node:62827) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. **In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.***

With async/await the above Warning is not displayed, since the function returns a Promise.
The same if I add a *return*:

```
@Post()
saveClient(@Param() params, @Body() createClientDto: ClientDto) {
   return this.clientRepository.save(createClientDto);
  }
```

So I'm a bit worried: a simple missing *return* may terminate my nestjs process?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Failure to return a promise in your first example means that nobody is paying attention when that operation has an error as there is no local `.catch()` so the only way for the caller to handle an error is for you to return it.  That's a fundamental promise programming mistake to not either return the promise so the caller can handle errors or to handle errors locally with `.catch()`.

Comment: I'd recommend using with `'@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises': 'error'`. NestJs handling (or NodeJS here) is correct - if you don't want to return this to the API client, you'll need an await. Otherwise use `return` (goes well with exception filters). In case you want to expect errors and still show "success" to the API client, use `.catch()` and handle it there.

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap it in  `try / catch`

```
@Post()
  async saveClient(@Param() params, @Body() createClientDto: ClientDto) {
    try {
       await this.clientRepository.save(createClientDto);
    } catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

- UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning means that every promise needs to be handled as it can potentially reject.
- "return" at controller handler will be basically be send as http body response. This could be of course interfered or impacted by interceptors, middleware and exception filter if you have any.

```
  @Post()
  saveClient(@Param() params, @Body() createClientDto: ClientDto) {
    return this.clientRepository.save(createClientDto)
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```